# Rotate direction in another hemisphere

Tags: c++, path, trace

As part of a Monte Carlo Path Tracing, I generate directions in a hemisphere like this.

```
double theta = acos(1 - 2 * uniformRandom01());
double phi = 2 * M_PI * uniformRandom01();
Vec direction(cos(theta) * cos(phi), sin(theta) * cos(phi), sin(phi));
```

However, these directions are generated in hemisphere where its center is a vector (0,1,0).

Now, i have an intersection point with its normal. How can I rotate the generated direction in order the put it in the hemiphere centered at the intersection point's normal ?

[Example of hemispheres](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTZpb.png)
This picture is from http://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/global-illumination-path-tracing

For example, the hemisphere of the generated direction is the bottom one. I want to put this direction in another hemisphere like the 2 ou 3 bounces hemispheres.

Tell me if it is not clear,

Thank you

Comment: _I can not seem to make it work._ This is your problem statement - maybe you should show us what you tried.

Comment: What do you mean by *"going up"*?

Comment: @erip ok this is not clear
The code above is generating uniformly a random direction within an hemisphere. The center of this hemisphere is a direction oriented (0,1,0). I am supposing that because there is no using of another vector.
Imagine there is at an intersection point, a normal N set as (0.5, 0.2, 0) and its hemisphere. How can I rotate the first generated direction in order to put it in the hemisphere centered at N ?

Comment: @Beta I mean by "going up", going to only y axis.